# Linux Mint system settings locked

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, settings

The system settings for my Linux Mint OS, for example desktop background or mouse speed or screen resolution etc. won't change, for some reason.

I just restarted my computer and for some reason the background had changed and the Computer icon was missing. When I tried to change these settings by going to the System Settings menu, the changes won't save.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an issue of permissions. Open the System Settings menu under root through terminal to get full access. I'd look at the permissions of those files though, do a whereis (config tool here) to find where the files are and post the permissions on them (ls -la | grep (config tool here))